# Impose access limits from Apache to prevent scraping?

Tags: php, apache, screen-scraping, limit

The problem is of a content website that is being scraped so badly that it breaks the server.

Is there an easy method of limiting access for IPs to a fixed number of requests at a time OR per day ? ( 10 pages / day or.... 10 pages every 2 minutes )

Ideally, I would keep a wildcard list for search engines and disallow everybody else from accessing content too fast or too much.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks guys  :D 

There's the discussion of requests. Each jpg/css/js/html would make a new request. 
This would mean I would have to average out how many requests are made per page as step1. Step2 would be to average a normal user's usage of the website in a given time frame. 

With this number in mind ( which would look like 800 requests per hour ), I would apply the restrictions via iptables/mod_security or another method ?

Answer (score 5):

One way around this, would be using IPTABLES (linux only) to prevent that individual IPs start more than a specified number of connections. It's trial and error, as you need to calculate it right, but in an overall, that should prevent the attacker's connection rate

```
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j STOP-ABUSE
iptables -A STOP-ABUSE -m recent --set
iptables -A STOP-ABUSE -m recent --update --seconds 10 --hitcount 3 -j DROP
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I would rather prefer doing that at the system level, using iptables...

But if you're looking for a solution based on Apache, an idea might be to use [`mod_security`](http://www.modsecurity.org/).

The [`SecGuardianLog`](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.12/html-multipage/configuration-directives.html#N10689) configuration directive looks especially interesting, in your case *(quoting)* :

> Description: Configuration directive
>   to use the httpd-guardian script to
>   monitor for Denial of Service (DoS)
>   attacks.
>
> By default httpd-guardian will defend
>   against clients that send more than
>   120 requests in a minute, or more than
>   360 requests in five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can install modules such as mod_bandwidth and mod_limitipconn to limit bandwidth usage (globally and per connection).

Check http://mansurovs.com/tech/apache-bandwidth-throttling for more info.